# Unable to run Python Django Oscar sandbox website on Windows

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I wanted to learn how to use Django and Oscar to create an e-commerce website. I was initially trying to follow some tutorials but almost all of them use some old version.

Finally, I tried to follow the official documentation. The only problem is that the instructions on the website seem to be for Linux. (https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.2/internals/sandbox.html).

Here are my commands I wrote in the terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar.git
cd django-oscar
virtualenv oscar
oscar\Scripts\Activate
```

These commands seem to have created all the folders. However,

```
make sandbox
sandbox/manage.py runserver
```

throws an error about the `make` not being recognized. I installed MinGW on my Windows but this did not seem to make any difference.

If I try to run the `manage.py runserver` command directly.

```
cd sandbox
manage.py runserver
```

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

How can I get the sample Django Oscar project to run?

Thanks.

Comment: This means the virtualenv might not have django installed, just use `pip install django-oscar` it will install Django and Django-oscar

Answer (score 0):

Just install the `requirements.txt` from the django-oscar folder using command:

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @amolpachpute but it gives me the following error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requirements.txt (from versions: none)`